# CoreData fetching all one-to-many relationship

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate

I have two classes, `Session` and `Course`, with a one-to-many relationship between a session and courses.  I'm trying to fetch all of a session's courses using an NSPredicate.  The predicates I have tried throw errors.

```
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Course> = Course.fetchRequest()

guard let startDate = session.startDate else {
   fatalError("Attempting to fetch courses for session without a start date")
}

let sessionPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "ALL %K == %@",
                                       #keyPath(Course.session.startDate),
                                       "\(startDate)")

fetchRequest.predicate = sessionPredicate
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find all courses whose session has a given start date it's easier:

```
let sessionPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "session.startDate == %@", startDate)
```

`NSManagedObject` provides full KVC support

Comment: Thanks, that worked, except I needed to cast startDate to NSDate.